# How to fixed the form fields alignment issues using css and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a form using bootstrap. When it displays an error, the div block below the error shifts to right. How can this be fixed using CSS?

This is a screenshot of how it looks after an error is shown:

[image]

**Code**

https://jsfiddle.net/yzm2aj9j/#&togetherjs=Q8Bk7CaMjy

```
<form>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="username" class="col-md-6 control-label">User Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="User Name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12" style="color:#ff5555;">
        <span class="error">User Name Cannot Be Blank</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-6 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="phone" class="col-md-6 control-label">Phone</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="phone">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-6 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-6 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-6 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Any piece of code would be nice.

Comment: We can't help you by just looking at an image. Please try to recreate that issue and make a fiddle with minimum possible code.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link just an demo

https://jsfiddle.net/yzm2aj9j/#&togetherjs=Q8Bk7CaMjy

Comment: Inserted code from OP's comment.

Comment: Each row (two `col-md-6` blocks) should be wrapped inside a `row` container (`<div class="row">...</div>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bootstrap's Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping):

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.
>
> If default grids are being used then rows should include a set of columns that add up to 12 or fewer (it is not required that you use all 12 available columns).

You need to wrap two `.col-xs-6` in one `.row`. Your code structure should be like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        // column content goes here...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        // column content goes here...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        // column content goes here...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        // column content goes here...
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="username" class="col-md-6 control-label">User Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="User Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="color:#ff5555;">
          <span class="error">User Name Cannot Be Blank</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-6 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="phone" class="col-md-6 control-label">Phone</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="phone">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-6 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-6 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-6 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```